# Select Max from each Subset

Tags: sql-server, max, subset

I'm banging my head here. I feel pretty stupid because I'm sure I've done something like this before, but can't for the life of me remember how. One of those days I guess >.<

Say I have the following data: ---> and a query which returns this: ---> But I want this:

```
ID   FirstID              ID   FirstID                ID   FirstID
--   -------              --   -------                --   -------
1     1                   1    1                      7    1
2     1                   3    3                      3    3
3     3                   4    4                      6    4
4     4                   5    5                      5    5
5     5
6     4
7     1
```

Notice that my query returns the records where ID = FirstID, but I want it to return the Max(ID) **for each subset** of unique FirstID. Sounds simple enough right? That's what I thought, but I keep getting back just record #7. Here's my query (the one that returns the second block of figures above) with some test code to make your life easier. I need this to give me the results in the far right block. It should be noted that this is a self-joining table where FirstID is a foreign key to ID. Thanks :)

```sql
declare @MyTable table (ID int, FirstID int)
insert into @MyTable values (1,1),(2,1),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,4),(7,1)
select ID, FirstID
from @MyTable
where ID = FirstID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work

```
declare @MyTable table (ID int, FirstID int)
insert into @MyTable values (1,1),(2,1),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,4),(7,1)

Select FirstID, Max (Id) ID
From @MyTable
Group BY FirstID
```

Results in

```
FirstID     ID
----------- -----------
1           7
3           3
4           6
5           5
```

Comment: HOT DOG!! I knew it was simple. Man, this just proves how tired I am *FACEDESK* Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

With SQL2005 and later SQL2008 versions the Aggregate functions in SQL Server have been improved

You can use PARTITION BY clause for example with MAX,MIN,SUM,COUNT functions

Please try the following example

```
select 
Distinct FirstID, Max(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY FirstID) MaxID
from @MyTable
```

You can find an example at http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx

Upon your comment, I modified the same query just to provide the exact output in order of rows and columns as follows

```
select Distinct 
    Max(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY FirstID) ID,
    FirstID
from @MyTable 
order by FirstID
```

Comment: thanks for the new syntax (wasn't familiar with partitions). I gave it a try, but while yielding the same results (albeit in a different order), performs less than half as well as the original answer. On the other hand, I haven't tested it for more complex data sets which joins and stuff, but I suspect it would yield the same?

Comment: The query returns the desired output, is not it? But the performance is not as good as the Raj's answer. But I wanted to demonstrate the aggrigation functions' usage with Partition By clause. You can use the same method in other issues where a simple Group By does not help