# How to return multiple values within a group of rows.

Tags: sql-server, max

I have tried to use Max(), subqueries, and joins, but my knowledge is limited enough that I am not sure how to organize them. I was willing to just use several nested select statements, knowing it could be resource intensive, but I can't get it to work.

I need to return any nulls, as well as the highest ConfigID for each Location.

```
TABLE
ID     Location     ConfigID
1      AA           NULL
2      AA           2
3      AA           1
4      BB           5
5      BB           4
6      BB           3
7      CC           NULL
8      CC           6
```

I want to see the results:

```
ID     Location     ConfigID
1      AA           NULL
2      AA           2
4      BB           5
7      CC           NULL
8      CC           6
```

I have tried:

```
select ID, Location, ConfigID
from Table
where ConfigID is null
      or configID = (select ConfigID
                     from table
                     where Location in (select distinct Location
                                        from Table
                                        order by ConfigID desc
                                        )
                     )
```

SQL server didn't like that because I cannot have an order by in a subquery unless Top is used. Now that I am looking at it again, I don't think that the order by is even within the correct subquery. It was as close as I could get. I was hopeful when I saw [Select Max from each subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130591/select-max-from-each-subset), but that was a dead-end, I think. Also, I don't believe that a self-join will work because the data I would self-join on is all in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Yes, you need to use `TOP 1`, what's wrong with that?

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Location, ConfigID
FROM myTable t1
WHERE ConfigID IS NULL
   OR ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID
            FROM myTable t2
            WHERE t2.Location = t1.Location
            ORDER BY ConfigID DESC)
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/692848/863685/).

Comment: I must have talked myself into not using Top for some reason. This worked well.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't put it in the right place, because you had two sub-queries. You can also do it with `union` as you can see in the other answers, but this answer is the simplest, and probably the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

You would better have separate queries for `NULL`s and highest `ConfigID` and then `UNION` them, then `ORDER BY ID`:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Location, ConfigId DESC) AS rn, *
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE ConfigID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 1, ID, Location, ConfigID
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE ConfigID IS NULL
)
SELECT ID, Location, ConfigID FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfb957/41/0).

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks for your feedback. Corrected SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one query to get the `NULL` entries and then a second query with `PARTITION BY` to get the top ConfigID row for each location. Finally do a `UNION ALL` to get the final result set and sort. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dab30/2/0. Query is below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    -- This query gets the NULL ConfigID entries.
    SELECT
        TestTable.ID,
        TestTable.[Location],
        TestTable.ConfigID
    FROM
        TestTable
    WHERE
        TestTable.ConfigID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- This query utilizes the PARTITION BY to get the max ConfigID for each group.
    SELECT
        TestTablePartitioned.ID,
        TestTablePartitioned.[Location],
        TestTablePartitioned.ConfigID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY
                    [Location] -- The column to group the partition by.
                ORDER BY
                    ConfigID DESC -- The column used to determine partition order.
            ) AS PartitionIndex,
            TestTable.ID,
            TestTable.[Location],
            TestTable.ConfigID
        FROM
            TestTable
        WHERE
            TestTable.ConfigID IS NOT NULL
    ) AS TestTablePartitioned
    WHERE
        TestTablePartitioned.PartitionIndex = 1 -- Gets the top entry (max ConfigID) for each location.
) AS TestTableUnion
ORDER BY
    TestTableUnion.[Location],
    TestTableUnion.ConfigID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
 FROM Table D WHERE 
  ConfigID = (SELECT MAX(ConfigID) FROM Table
   WHERE Location=D.Location )
        Union 
Select * From Table
   Where ConfigID Is NULL
order by Location
```

Comment: I did not know about union. In general is it a better use of resources to have a union, or a subquery? Or, because they are both running two queries, is it essentially the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- ID     Location     ConfigID

WITH CTE_TMP (ID, LOCATION, CONFIGID)
AS
(
SELECT 1 ID, 'AA' LOCATION, NULL CONFIGID
UNION
SELECT 2, 'AA', 2
UNION
SELECT 3, 'AA', 1
UNION
SELECT 4, 'BB', 5
UNION
SELECT 5, 'BB', 4
UNION
SELECT 6, 'BB', 3
UNION
SELECT 7, 'CC', NULL
UNION
SELECT 8, 'CC', 6
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, LOCATION, CONFIGID FROM CTE_TMP WHERE CONFIGID IS NULL
UNION
SELECT A.ID, A.LOCATION, B.CONFIGID
FROM CTE_TMP A
  JOIN (SELECT LOCATION, MAX(CONFIGID) CONFIGID FROM CTE_TMP
       GROUP BY LOCATION) B ON A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION AND A.CONFIGID = B.CONFIGID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Location, ConfigID
FROM Table
WHERE ConfigID IS NULL 
      OR ID = (SELECT ID FROM Table AS t2 
                       WHERE t2.Location = Table.Location
                                          ORDER BY ConfigID DESC LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY Location
```

Comment: The question is for SQL Server, not MySQL WHICH is what your query will work. There is no `LIMIT` in SQL Server.